# How to parse WebElement

Tags: java, parsing, selenium

In debug mode I can see that locator of one of the element on the page is: **By.name: NameOfMyElement_123**.

The question is, how can I parse the following string `(By.name: NameOfMyElement_123)` in Java in order to have the type of my locator (`name`) and value (`NameOfMyElement_123`) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] split = "By.name: NameOfMyElement_123".split(" ");
```

or

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w.]*): ([\\w]*_[\\d]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("By.name: NameOfMyElement_123");
    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vladislav, I also came to this decision, but I need nly type of the locator , not by.name, only "name"

Comment: Try it:
 `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w].([\\w]*): ([\\w]*_[\\d]*)");`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()`. In this case, it's best to split with `:`

```
String[] splittedText = element.split(':');
String type = splittedText[0].trim();
String value = splittedText[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy is necessary, two split() methods are enough:

```
String[] firstSplit = element.split(':');
String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[0].split('.');

String type = secondSplit[1].trim(); // will result in "name"
String value = firstSplit[1].trim(); // will result in "NameOfMyElement_123"
```